# MySQL Single Quote Efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance

I live in Australia, so postcodes are numeric and four digits long.

In a table steup by another person the postcode field has been setup as a VARCHAR(10) - strange i know!!!

There is a difference between the following two query times:
Postcode='3000'
Postcode=3000

Both queries run, but the one with single quotes around it runs between 50% to 80% faster.  Likewise postcode IN('3000','3001','3002') is much faster than Postcode IN(3000,3001,3002).  The postcode field is indexed

The quesiton is HOW do the single quotes make so much speed difference?

Can anyone shed any light on how the engine optimizes the above queries?

Comment: perhaps you should post both the query plans

Comment: but, there is obviously some casting of datatypes occuring

Comment: Query Plan for WITHOUT QUOTES:id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE August ALL IDX_Postcode \N \N \N 700958 100.00 Using where

Comment: Query Plan for WITH QUOTES  
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE August ref IDX_Postcode IDX_Postcode 12 const 35662 100.00 Using where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one important trap in this. 
If you use something like

```
 code = 1000
```

instead of

```
code = '1000'
```

then if you had other dataset, the first case would return all records like:

```
 '1000', '1000A', '1000B'
```

etc, while the second would return as expected  only '1000'. This might be the reason of performance issue. Some mentioned that it converts int to varchar. I believe it converts all varchars to int and that is why it is noticable

Comment: Just tested this out on a temp table and yeah it works exactly as stated.  Thats interesting!  Though surely if it converts varchar to int CODE=1000 would not return 1000A and 1000B?

Comment: i am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
It is converting '1000' to 1000, '1000A' to 1000 and '1000B' to 1000. That is why 3 results are returned, because the condition is code=1000 :) so they satisfy the condition, right?

Answer (score 2):

When you don't include the quotes, the interpreter has to take the time to do an implicit conversion from `int` to `varchar`. If you use quotes, it's already a `varchar` and it saves the time of doing a conversion to the native storage format.

Comment: Ahh right, that makes sense.  Should have been obvious really espically since i'm a Delphi programmer - i'm used to working in a typesafe environment so i should have spotted the necessity of the optimizer converting the values!!!

Comment: @Derek are you sure it is converting int to varchar? please observe my answer. I believe this answer is wrong :)